# How to find the highest value, next lowest value, then the next highest value in a python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I want to find the highest and lowest values from a python list as mentioned below.

```
myList = [10,12,18,20,25,18,17,16,10,20,30,35,40,35,30,20,15]
```

I want to find The first highest value found in this list(25), Next is the lowest value after the first highest value in the list(10), then next highest value after the previous lowest value(40), Thus the lowest and highest values respectively until the end of the list and their respective index values.

So what I tried a lot was finding the highest value and the lowest value in a list, but I want to find the lowest and highest values respectively until the end of the list and their respective index values.

Comment: What exactly does "the first highest value" mean?  Why is this value 25?

Comment: `next(x for x,y in zip(myList, myList[1:]) if y<x)`

Comment: @JohnGordon Looks like they mean local max and min. E.g. 25 is the first peak, 10 is the next trough, etc.

Comment: you have to get three values and check `x1 < x2 and  x2 > x3` to search `local max`. And you have to move to next index on list and again get three values, etc. At the same time you can check `x1 > x2 and  x2 < x3` to search `local min`. Eventually It may need to use `>=`, `<=` instead of `>`, `<`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all the vertices in one iteration.

Create a flag that indicates if you are looking for min or max now.

```
my_list = [10, 12, 18, 20, 25, 18, 17, 16, 10, 20, 30, 35, 40, 35, 30, 20, 15]

flag = 'up'
indexes = list()
```

Iterate through the list, when you find max, change the flag to 'down' and go on looking for the minimum. And so on.

```
for i in range(len(my_list) - 1):

    if flag == 'up' and (my_list[i] > my_list[i+1]):
        indexes.append(i)
        flag = 'down'

    elif flag == 'down' and (my_list[i] < my_list[i+1]):
        indexes.append(i)
        flag = 'up'

indexes.append(len(my_list) - 1)

values = [my_list[index] for index in indexes]

print(indexes)  # Output: [4, 8, 12, 16]
print(values)  # Output: [25, 10, 40, 15]
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this using a Python dictionary also.

Comment: Do you want the output to be a dictionary?
Create a dictionary instead of a list of indexes.
Here is the code in a better format: https://prnt.sc/e571dWfFuNv4
results = dict()

for i in range(len(my_list) - 1):

    if flag == 'up' and (my_list[i] > my_list[i+1]):
        results[i] = my_list[i]
        flag = 'down'

    elif flag == 'down' and (my_list[i] < my_list[i+1]):
        results[i] = my_list[i]
        flag = 'up'

results[len(my_list) - 1] = my_list[-1]

print(results)

Answer (score 2):

You could try using groupby:

```
myList = [10,12,18,20,25,18,17,16,10,20,30,35,40,35,30,20,15]

from itertools import groupby

d = [ (myList[i],i) for _,(*_,i) in groupby(range(1,len(myList)),
                                    key=lambda i:myList[i-1]<myList[i]) ]

print(d)
[(25, 4), (10, 8), (40, 12), (15, 16)]
```

You could also compute the indexes first and get the values separately:

```
myList = [10,12,18,20,25,18,17,16,10,20,30,35,40,35,30,20,15]

from itertools import groupby,accumulate

d         = (b>a for a,b in zip(myList,myList[1:]))
*indexes, = accumulate(len(g) for _,(*g,) in groupby(d)) 
values    = [myList[i] for i in indexes]

print(indexes)
print(values)

[4, 8, 12, 16]
[25, 10, 40, 15]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) in itertools to find the local max and min:

```
import itertools as it 

myList = [10,12,18,20,25,18,17,16,10,20,30,35,40,35,30,20,15]

for k,v in it.groupby(zip(myList, myList[1:]), lambda t: t[0]<t[1] ):
    print(list(v)[-1][-1], "Max" if k else "Min")
```

Prints:

```
25 Max
10 Min
40 Max
15 Min
```

If you want the indices:

```
for k,v in it.groupby(enumerate(zip(myList, myList[1:]),1), 
                                   lambda t: t[1][0]<t[1][1]):
    i,(_,x)=list(v)[-1]
    print(f"{i}:", x, "Max" if k else "Min")
```

Prints:

```
4: 25 Max
8: 10 Min
12: 40 Max
16: 15 Min
```

If the final index would NOT be considered a min, you can use python 3.10+ [pattern matching](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/) to do a comparison on the two values around a potential max/min:

```
for i,(x,y,z) in enumerate(zip(myList, myList[1:], myList[2:]),1):
    match (x < y > z), (x > y < z):
        case True, False:
            print(f"{i}: {y} max")
            
        case False, True:
            print(f"{i}: {y} min") 

        # add a False, False case if you want to print all
```

Or a big 'ole list comprehension to replicate that functionality for Python < 3.10:

```
rst_index={(True,False):"max", (False,True):"min"}
[f"{t[0]}: {t[1]} {rst_index[tuple(t[2:])]}" for t in (
     (i,y,(x < y > z), (x > y < z)) 
        for i,(x,y,z) in 
            enumerate(zip(myList, myList[1:], myList[2:]),1) ) 
                if any(t[2:]) ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should get three values from list and check

- `x1 < x2 > x3` to get `local max`
- `x1 > x2 < x3` to get `local min`

This is situation where you could use `for`-loop with `range(len(...))` to work with `index`
to get three values `myList[index-1]`, `myList[index]`, `myList[index+1]` (instead of single value).

You should  start at second item (`index = 1`) instead of first (`index = 0`)
because code uses `index-1`

And you should stop on `len(myList)-1` instead of `len(myList)`
because code uses `index+1`

```
for i in range(1, len(myList)-1):
    print(myList[i-1], myList[i], myList[i+1])
```

and check

```
   is_max = (myList[i-1] < myList[i] > myList[i+1])
   is_min = (myList[i-1] > myList[i] < myList[i+1])
```

And later use `is_max` and `is_min` to display or keep values

```
    if is_max:
        # ... code ...
    elif is_min:
        # ... code ...
    else:
        # ... code ...
```

---

Full working example:

```
myList = [10,12,18,20,25,18,17,16,10,20,30,35,40,35,30,20,15]

for i in range(1, len(myList)-1):

    is_max = (myList[i-1] < myList[i] > myList[i+1])
    is_min = (myList[i-1] > myList[i] < myList[i+1])

    if is_max:
        print(f'{i:3} |', myList[i-1], myList[i], myList[i+1], 'max')
    elif is_min:
        print(f'{i:3} |', myList[i-1], myList[i], myList[i+1], 'min')
    else:
        print(f'{i:3} |', myList[i-1], myList[i], myList[i+1])
```

Result:

```
  1 | 10 12 18
  2 | 12 18 20
  3 | 18 20 25
  4 | 20 25 18 max
  5 | 25 18 17
  6 | 18 17 16
  7 | 17 16 10
  8 | 16 10 20 min
  9 | 10 20 30
 10 | 20 30 35
 11 | 30 35 40
 12 | 35 40 35 max
 13 | 40 35 30
 14 | 35 30 20
 15 | 30 20 15
```

---

Eventually you should use `>=`, `<=` instead of `>`, `<`